# error when using bestglm() in bestglm package

Tags: r, glm

Getting the following error message using the bestglm() function from the bestglm package:

> Error in bestglm(modeling_data_for_best_glm, family = Gamma(link = "log")) : input matrix must have numeric or factor variables only

I thought for some reason that the response variable had to be the first column in the dataframe and named "y", and I did that, but it doesn't seem to have helped as I'm still getting the error.

How would I quickly/efficiently fix my dataframe so I can use this function if I have a lot of variables?

Comment: Could you show us the code you ran (as text/code block, not as an image/snapshot) and a `summary()` of your data frame? Ideally, a *reproducible* example ...

Comment: Also, based on the examples, I think the response is the *last* column of the data frame.  Do you have columns that are character that you should be converting to factor?